# How to retrieve oneway taxiways from Overpas API?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, nominatim, overpass-turbo, osmnx

I have was able to make a query to http://overpass-turbo.eu/ where I request the taxiways of a specific airport like this:

```
[out:xml]/*fixed by auto repair*/[timeout:25];
// fetch area “airport” to search in
area[icao~"LOWW"]->.searchArea;
// gather results
(

  // query part for: “taxiway”
  node["aeroway"="taxiway"](area.searchArea);
  way["aeroway"="taxiway"](area.searchArea);
  relation["aeroway"="taxiway"](area.searchArea);

);
// print results
out meta;/*fixed by auto repair*/
>;
out meta qt;/*fixed by auto repair*/
```

When I check the tags I see that there is an information I would like to have but I don't know how to get it. Basically I would like to make sure that all the taxiways have also the tag `oneway=yes`. I tried to achive my goal by modifying the line of code in the following way:

```
way["oneway"="yes"]["aeroway"="taxiway"](area.searchArea);
```

But with no success. Would you be able to provide a possible way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Well, most taxiways don't have a oneway=yes tag, so your query won't return anything. This is totally expected.

Comment: Ok perfect! I thought it was possible to force it to get that tag as well :)